# php.ini changes are not working in docker running on Mac

Tags: php, apache, docker

I have created a docker file, which running perfectly on Linux system. I am trying to do the same on Mac system but in Mac php.ini changes are not working.

Is anyone have idea about this issue.

Comment: Did you restart your apache server?

Comment: Yes, and main issue is with docker apache

Comment: It's a little obvious who you have only two options: A) you're editing an incorrect php.ini (remember there's a php.ini for fpm, other for cli, etc... or B) you didn't restart the correct daemon (If you use fpm you need to restart php-fpm, for example).